# Sorting data from array from a xml file

Tags: php, arrays, xml, sorting

I am in need of help to figure out something.

On my last question I was talking about parsing a XML and listing the values on html: [Parse XML to HTML with PHP SimpleXMLElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32540719/parse-xml-to-html-with-php-simplexmlelement)

I got that going really well, but then a new variable presented itself. :)

This is my XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<AdXML>

<Response>
    <Campaign>
        <Overview>
            <Name>strip</Name>
                <Description>category</Description>
                <Status>L</Status>
        </Overview>
        <Pages>
            <Url>page01</Url>
            <Url>page02</Url>
            <Url>page03</Url>
        </Pages>
    </Campaign>
</Response>
</AdXML>
```

My problem start when my XML generate the page's list random.so, one time it would load like this and another time it will load like this:

```
    <?xml version='1.0'?>
<AdXML>

<Response>
    <Campaign>
        <Overview>
            <Name>strip</Name>
                <Description>category</Description>
                <Status>L</Status>
        </Overview>
        <Pages>
            <Url>page02</Url>
            <Url>page03</Url>
            <Url>page01</Url>
        </Pages>
    </Campaign>
</Response>
</AdXML>
```

So I went from a simple:

```
<?php foreach ($xmlparsed->Response->Campaign->Pages->Url as $Url) {echo $Url, '<br>';} ?>
```

to:

```
<?php 
    $urlarray = array();
    foreach ($xmlparsed->Response->Campaign->Pages->Url as $Url) {$urlarray[] = $Url;}
    sort($urlarray);
    foreach ($urlarray as $key => $val){echo $key,'|',$val, '<br>';}
?>
```

What I am trying to do is to create an array with the information and then sort the pages alphabetically. I do not understand why cant I sort by value (pages), I can only sort by key and that defeat the purpose just because the xml is generated dynamically and I have no control on how it is formed.

ay help would be greatly appreciated .

cheers

Comment: might try it like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15604459/sorting-the-table-fields-using-simple-xml-and-xpath/15625514#15625514

Answer (score 0):

Look at `asort` and similar functions in PHP, there are a few that will help.

Comment: mmm, have you had a look at the comparision functions in it.
[link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php)

Comment: you are right I could do it with: sort($urlarray, SORT_STRING );

Comment: Great glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

This is the case of customized sorting array, in this case I suggest using **usort**:

For PHP version >= 5.4:

```
usort($urlarray, function ($a, $b) {
    if ((int)substr($a, 4, 2) > (int)substr($b, 4, 2)) return 1;
    elseif ((int)substr($a, 4, 2) < (int)substr($b, 4, 2)) return -1;
    else return 0;
});
```

For PHP version < 5.4:

```
function custom_sort($a, $b) {
    if ((int)substr($a, 4, 2) > (int)substr($b, 4, 2)) return 1;
    elseif ((int)substr($a, 4, 2) < (int)substr($b, 4, 2)) return -1;
    else return 0;
}

// then using in usort
usort($urlarray, 'custom_sort');
```

Hope this help.
Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it using a SORT_STRING:

```
<?php 
    $urlarray = array();
    foreach ($xmlparsed->Response->Campaign->Pages->Url as $Url) {$urlarray[] = $Url;}
    sort($urlarray, SORT_STRING);
    foreach ($urlarray as $key => $val){echo $key,'|',$val, '<br>';}
?>
```

thank you all